# Count XML child with the same name on each parent node

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, linq

I have following XML file:

```
<if:Cuerpo Renglon="1" Cantidad="13" Concepto="SOPORTE DE FARO" PUnitario="387.04" Importe="5031.52" U_x0020_de_x0020_M="PIEZA" Material="F01030106" cfdiClaveProdServ="31162504" cfdiClaveUnidad="H87" cfdiDescuento="2113.24">
  <if:Aduana CodigoMultiple="Aduana" PedimentoAduanero="14  51  3475  4000268" />
  <if:Aduana CodigoMultiple="Aduana" PedimentoAduanero="14  51  3475  4000268" />
  <if:Aduana CodigoMultiple="Aduana" PedimentoAduanero="14  51  3475  4000507" />
  <if:Aduana CodigoMultiple="Aduana" PedimentoAduanero="14  51  3475  4000874" />
  <if:Traslado CodigoMultiple="TrasladoConcepto" cfdiBase="2918.28" cfdiImpuesto="002" cfdiTipoFactor="Tasa" cfdiTasaOCuota="0.160000" cfdiImporte="466.92" />
</if:Cuerpo>
<if:Cuerpo Renglon="2" Cantidad="13" Concepto="SOPORTE DE FARO" PUnitario="387.04" Importe="5031.52" U_x0020_de_x0020_M="PIEZA" Material="F01030106" cfdiClaveProdServ="31162504" cfdiClaveUnidad="H87" cfdiDescuento="2113.24">
  <if:Aduana CodigoMultiple="Aduana" PedimentoAduanero="14  51  3475  4000268" />
  <if:Aduana CodigoMultiple="Aduana" PedimentoAduanero="14  51  3475  4000268" />
  <if:Traslado CodigoMultiple="TrasladoConcepto" cfdiBase="2918.28" cfdiImpuesto="002" cfdiTipoFactor="Tasa" cfdiTasaOCuota="0.160000" cfdiImporte="466.92" />
</if:Cuerpo>
```

I want to count how many `if:Aduana` node each `if:Cuerpo` parent node has.

For example, the first `if:Cuerpo` node has 4 `if:Aduana` child nodes
and the second `if:Cuerpo` node has 2 `if:Aduana` child nodes.

this is the complete namespace

```
  <cfdi:Addenda xmlns:if="https://www.interfactura.com/Schemas/Documentos" >
    <if:FacturaInterfactura TipoDocumentoId="0" TipoDocumento="Factura" Id="303019096">
      <if:Emisor RI="0000915" />
      <if:Receptor RI="9900136962" Activo="False" />
      <if:Encabezado IdInterno="303019096" TemplateId="78000937" Folio="928" FolioSerie="928-" SerieFolio="-928" MonedaDoc="MXN" MonedaDesc="Pesos" Status="1" CFD="True" Estatus="Por Pagar" ProcesoId="0" CondicionPago="60 días a partir entrega factu" Descuento="2113.24" SubTotal="5031.52" Total="3385.20" Moneda="MXN" LugarExpedicion="09319" TipoCambio="1.00000" TipoDocumento="Factura" metodoDePago="PUE" formaDePago="03" FolioReferencia="0740642450" RegimenFiscalEmisor="623" cfdiUsoCFDI="P01" cfdiFormaPago="03" cfdiMetodoPago="PUE" cfdiTipoRelacion="" VersionCFDI="3.3" Fecha="2017-11-18T14:15:41" cadenaOriginal="||1.1|199BEA24-32BC-4E30-8041-5DC1EADC70D8|2017-11-18T14:14:42|INT020124V62||8wyc7rDr2Vv9toCY/4ByZxrZIBYUtSycm2k6xZB5Rmgg+e5Cra1xhCArZR2w9y4K845Mr1xzxfVda6xUGie0YjKZYrlXRrhigvQ4K3EGUsFOYenDaT0DnzSIUCu8OhwBCaPsspUJzCngev6YqSPjjoCZATsvl21hljxXPuRjGjyJa8wYGUCWZzlU5ZfR65qjai9nNC0XeDyxGfZAwewbZL17RMLnH73TpPJbe7muGd1ts19EGVWCa22avj1SGBIjxJ1Dz+TPhuXk5qNI/iO5XLQWqWMUXVgnZrOSh7Gm2iR+E8Q5QV6fIytQj4g/K1EPyDJ6aD12zh4set3w+/Dn2Q==|20001000000300022323||" cadenaOriginalTimbre="||1.1|199BEA24-32BC-4E30-8041-5DC1EADC70D8|2017-11-18T14:14:42|INT020124V62||8wyc7rDr2Vv9toCY/4ByZxrZIBYUtSycm2k6xZB5Rmgg+e5Cra1xhCArZR2w9y4K845Mr1xzxfVda6xUGie0YjKZYrlXRrhigvQ4K3EGUsFOYenDaT0DnzSIUCu8OhwBCaPsspUJzCngev6YqSPjjoCZATsvl21hljxXPuRjGjyJa8wYGUCWZzlU5ZfR65qjai9nNC0XeDyxGfZAwewbZL17RMLnH73TpPJbe7muGd1ts19EGVWCa22avj1SGBIjxJ1Dz+TPhuXk5qNI/iO5XLQWqWMUXVgnZrOSh7Gm2iR+E8Q5QV6fIytQj4g/K1EPyDJ6aD12zh4set3w+/Dn2Q==|20001000000300022323||" cadenaOriginalEmisor="||3.3|928|2017-11-18T14:15:41|03|00001000000405697777|60 días a partir entrega factu|5031.52|2113.24|MXN|1.00000|3385.20|I|PUE|09319|CMC0712144R4|COMERCIALIZADORA DE MOTOCICLETAS DE CALIDAD, S.A. DE C.V.|623|PERP660325R60|PEDRO PEREYRA RABAGO|P01|31162504|13|H87|PIEZA|SOPORTE DE FARO|387.04|5031.52|2113.24|2918.28|002|Tasa|0.160000|466.92|14 51 3475 4000268|14 51 3475 4000268|14 51 3475 4000507|14 51 3475 4000874|002|Tasa|0.160000|466.92|466.92||" importeConLetra="**********************TRES MIL TRESCIENTOS OCHENTA Y CINCO PESOS 20/100 M.N.**********************">
        <if:Cuerpo Renglon="1" Cantidad="13" Concepto="SOPORTE DE FARO" PUnitario="387.04" Importe="5031.52" U_x0020_de_x0020_M="PIEZA" Material="F01030106" cfdiClaveProdServ="31162504" cfdiClaveUnidad="H87" cfdiDescuento="2113.24">
          <if:Aduana CodigoMultiple="Aduana" PedimentoAduanero="14  51  3475  4000268" />
          <if:Aduana CodigoMultiple="Aduana" PedimentoAduanero="14  51  3475  4000268" />
          <if:Aduana CodigoMultiple="Aduana" PedimentoAduanero="14  51  3475  4000507" />
          <if:Aduana CodigoMultiple="Aduana" PedimentoAduanero="14  51  3475  4000874" />
          <if:Traslado CodigoMultiple="TrasladoConcepto" cfdiBase="2918.28" cfdiImpuesto="002" cfdiTipoFactor="Tasa" cfdiTasaOCuota="0.160000" cfdiImporte="466.92" />
        </if:Cuerpo>
        <if:Cuerpo Renglon="2" Cantidad="13" Concepto="SOPORTE DE FARO" PUnitario="387.04" Importe="5031.52" U_x0020_de_x0020_M="PIEZA" Material="F01030106" cfdiClaveProdServ="31162504" cfdiClaveUnidad="H87" cfdiDescuento="2113.24">
          <if:Aduana CodigoMultiple="Aduana" PedimentoAduanero="14  51  3475  4000268" />
          <if:Aduana CodigoMultiple="Aduana" PedimentoAduanero="14  51  3475  4000268" />
          <if:Aduana CodigoMultiple="Aduana" PedimentoAduanero="14  51  3475  4000507" />
          <if:Aduana CodigoMultiple="Aduana" PedimentoAduanero="14  51  3475  4000874" />
          <if:Traslado CodigoMultiple="TrasladoConcepto" cfdiBase="2918.28" cfdiImpuesto="002" cfdiTipoFactor="Tasa" cfdiTasaOCuota="0.160000" cfdiImporte="466.92" />
        </if:Cuerpo>
      </if:Encabezado>
    </if:FacturaInterfactura>
```

Comment: Could you take a bit more time to explain what you mean by "I want to count how many if:Aduana has each if:Cuerpo or how many PedimentoAduanero has each if:Cuerpo"? In particular the "has each" parts aren't clear to me at all at the moment. What does the "1 - 4, 2 - 2" mean?

Comment: (It's great that you've given us sample XML by the way, but I'd reduce it to just the elements and attributes that are important, for clarity.)

Comment: Ok I updated the question i hope its better understood

Comment: @JonSkeet I believe he means the first (1) `if:Cuerpo` has 4 `if:Aduana` and the second (2) `if:Cuerpo` has 2 `if:Aduana`.

Comment: I'm still not sure what you mean by "has each if:Cuerpo parent node". Do you just mean how many if:Aduana nodes have if:Cuerpo parent nodes? Isn't that all 6 of them here?

Comment: @aaron: Possibly. I'm hoping we can get more clarity so we don't have to guess.

Comment: as @aaron mentioned i want to know how many if:Aduana are in each if:Cuerpo

Comment: and what's the namespace?

Comment: Right, it's definitely getting clearer. So a list or array with entries of 4 and 2 would be okay? As derloopkat says, we need to know what namespace "if" corresponds to (a minimal but complete XML file would help here) and then it should be simple enough.

Comment: ok, english is not my fist language, its kind of hard to express what i want, i updated the question to introduce the   namespace "if"

Comment: Yes, you have provided a definition for `if` prefix by inserting a new dependency for another prefix `cfdi`. So again, what is `cfdi` ? If this depends on another prefix then please provide all of them.

Comment: ohh ok a get it if is Interfactura a service that provides billing services and CFDI is the version of the billing service, thas all the prefix that the xml uses

Comment: @hugocarrillo, me refiero a que `xmlns:if` está definiendo que es `if`, entonces debe haber un `xmlns:cfdi` y asi sucesivamente con todos los prefijos que use tu xml.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @derloopkat, first you need to add `cfdi` XML namespace to XML file, and also ending tag for `cfdi:Addenda`. Otherwise XML document is not valid and cannot be processed. For example:

```
<cfdi:Addenda xmlns:cfdi="https://cfdi.namespace" xmlns:if="https://www.interfactura.com/Schemas/Documentos">
...
</cfdi:Addenda>
```

You can then load XML file with `XDocument` class and use [Linq to XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098(v=vs.100).aspx) query to count `if:Aduana` elements.

```
const string IF_NAMESPACE = "https://www.interfactura.com/Schemas/Documentos";
const string PATH_TO_XML_FILE = @"C:\path_to_xml_file.xml";

// Load XML document from file
var doc = XDocument.Load(PATH_TO_XML_FILE);

// select all if:Cuerpo elements
var cuerpoElements = doc.Descendants(XName.Get("Cuerpo", IF_NAMESPACE));

// for each if:Cuerpo element, count it's descendant if:Aduana elements
// aduanaElementsCount contains array [4, 4]
var aduanaElementsCount = cuerpoElements.Select(cuerpo => cuerpo.Descendants(XName.Get("Aduana", IF_NAMESPACE)).Count()).ToArray();
```

Sometimes I prefer using XPath query rather than Linq to XML, as it sometimes leads to shorter code. It is actually bit more complicated in this particular case, but you can still use it with the same result:

```
const string IF_NAMESPACE = "https://www.interfactura.com/Schemas/Documentos";
const string PATH_TO_XML_FILE = @"C:\path_to_xml_file.xml";

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
// Load XML document from file
doc.Load(PATH_TO_XML_FILE);

// Create namespace manager for XML namespaces used in XPath query
var ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
ns.AddNamespace("if", IF_NAMESPACE);

var aduanaElementsCount = doc
    .SelectNodes("//if:Cuerpo", ns)// returns all if:Cuerpo nodes in XML document
    .Cast<IEnumerable>()// enables enumeration of selected nodes
    .Select(cuerpo => (cuerpo as XmlNode).SelectNodes(".//if:Aduana", ns).Count)// for each if:Cuerpo element, count it's descendant if:Aduana elements
    .ToArray();//returns array [4, 4]
```